# R: Cannot use 0-cloud to install.packages

Tags: r, rstudio

When I try to install packages from 0-cloud it doesn't work

```
> install.packages("lfactors")
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
```

then I select 0-cloud from the list of repositories. and R returns

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning message:
package ‘lfactors’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

But, when I run this code and select another repository it does work.

I tried turning off my proxy server, and visiting the site with the proxy server on and I can visit it in the browser with no issue.

Any ideas?

Edit:
based on a comment, I ran this

```
capabilities()["libcurl"]
libcurl 
   TRUE
```

So I think it's not that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your R binary may have been built without curl support, and you cannot access https servers. See what this returns:

```
R> capabilities()["libcurl"]
libcurl 
   TRUE 
R>
```

In case this is `FALSE` for you, do two things:

1. Change `options("repos")` to use http instead of https.
2. Rebuild R to have libcurl support.

I do this in `Rprofile.site`:

```
## Example of Rprofile.site
local({
    r <- getOption("repos")
    r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.rstudio.com"    ## not https for you
    options(repos = r)
})
```

Edit:  Another possibility, particularly on Windows, is that the internet2 dll has to be activate, so running `setInternet2(TRUE)` once should help.

Comment: I edited the question, but that doesn't look like that what it is. I have the Windows binary built by the R team.

Comment: I see, Can you try `setInternet2(TRUE) ` before the `install.packages()` call?

Comment: IIRC it enables something which libcurl needs.  This was recently made the default (on Windows) for the next R release as well. See eg [here for the NEWS entry](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/2015/07/07#n2015-07-07).

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer if it suggests this. I'm not sure what forum etiquette says, am  I supposed to edit it?

Comment: I can do that, and I appreciate that you asked first :)