# How do I rebuild R to have libcurl support?

Tags: r, libcurl

I've been having trouble installing packages in R 3.2.2, evidently because I'm not configured for libcurl.  The answer provided at the link below suggests either to 1) Change options("repos") to use http instead of https, or 2) rebuild R to have libcurl support.  I was able to change the options, and that worked for now, but rebuilding R to have libcurl support sounds like a longer term fix.  How do I do that?

[R: Cannot use 0-cloud to install.packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413912/r-cannot-use-0-cloud-to-install-packages/31413989#31413989)

If platform matters, I am running Ubuntu Precise, and install R using Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: Simply for confirmation, what is the output of `capabilities("libcurl")`?

Comment: Do you have libcurl installed properly on your system?

Comment: The output of capabilities("libcurl") is FALSE.